# ASP.NET server and PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net

I wanted to know, is a server that supports ASP.NET and PHP on the same box common? wordpress/mediaWiki/phpBB3 seem like a nice combo but i am developing a ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 1):

Most windows webhosts support PHP as well. Big drawback to PHP being lack of URL rewriting support. IIS handles multiple handlers pretty well, so running both concurrently isn't even particularly tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Microsoft Web Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/Web/downloads/platform.aspx) if you want to have a drop in replacement, otherwise PHP will install into IIS as a SAPI module or, if you are using IIS 7 you can also run it as FastCGI.

php|architect is also giving away the [May 2009](http://www.phparch.com/c/magazine/issue/97) issue which is all about running PHP on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using IIS will certainly help you.

Download Microsoft's PHP for IIS, here, http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx

This'll help you start.

Don't forget to edit php.ini either in C:/Windows, or whereever the application was installed to, in order to ensure everything is set optimally for you.

> We know PHP hasn’t always run smoothly on the Windows platform, so we’ve now optimized Windows Server to support your PHP applications through a new component: FastCGI. FastCGI works as an interface between PHP engine and IIS, and it ensures that PHP runs much faster than with CGI and way more reliable than PHP ISAPI.

Answer (score 0):

with IIS you can host Asp.net and [PHP](http://php.iis.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the Phalanger project that integrates PHP so you can use it either separately or inside ASP.NET on IIS.

It is compiled down so it should run much faster than standard interpreted php.

[Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.ne)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ubuntu Server (which a variety of hosting providers offer), among other GNU/Linux distros.  Take a look at http://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+server+hosting , then just get apt-get [Mono for ASP.NET](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET), along with PHP 5:

sudo apt-get install mono-xsp2 php5

and anything else you need.